# NSDictionary vs custom objects for performance

Tags: iphone, memory, object, plist

I'm retrieving a pList, generated by some php i wrote, from a server using NSURLConnection.  My Plist contains several arrays at the root level.  These array contain sever NSDictionyObjects. Once I retrieve the pList I use NSPropertyLitSerialization to serialize the data into a NSDictionary.

Now, once I have this NSDictionary I load the values into to custom objects I have created with the following code.

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

//Create object array.
for (NSString *key in dict) {
NSArray *tempArr = [dict objectForKey:key]; 
NSMutableArray *gameObjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]             
                                        initWithCapacity:tempArr.count];    
for (NSDictionary *tempDict in tempArr) {
    //Build Objects and add to array

    GameObject *tempGame = [[GameObject alloc] initWithArr:tempDict];
            //initWithArr initializes the values in the object using tempDict
    [gameObjectArray addObject:tempGame];
    [tempGame release];
    }


    [newDict setObject:gameObjectArray forKey:key];
    [gameObjectArray release];
}

self.gameObjectsDict = newDict;
```

From this point forward I use the value objects stored gameObjectsDict throughout my application.  For all kinds of stuff including rendering UITableViews and passing data to other viewControllers/views.

My Question:
Is it worth it to put all these values from my pList into value Objects?

Before, I was just using the NSDictionary to pass my values around the app and it worked fine.  I felt it will be easier to code and a better practice to use the value objects but now that Im using the value objects if feels like I'm wasting more memory.  It feels like I'm passing these heavy objects full of data around where as before i was just grabbing a values from my dictionary when needed.

Answer (score 0):

One benefit to using custom objects would be type safety. When you are using objectForKey in lot's of places it may be hard to remember which type of object has which keys. Having the compiler remember this for you is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be treating the dictionaries as objectes, it is better practice to add the values to a custom object. It really doesn't use up as much memory as you would think. Also, it will enhance the readability of your code, which is always a plus.